# Force.com Site URL Redirect Lightning Community

Tags: aura, force.com-sites, lightning-community, redirect

Does the Force.com Site URL redirect only work with the actual Force.com Site and not the `/s` Lightning Community?

[image]

[image]

For example, if I create a redirect from `/s/foo` to `https://www.google.com` and navigate to `https://{myCommunityDomain}/s/foo`, nothing happens. However, if I remove the `/s` and navigate to `https://{myCommunityDomain}/foo` I am redirected to Google.

Is this expected behavior? If so, is the only way to redirect in a lightning community is to create a custom component like this

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" access="global">
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navigationService" />
</aura:component>


cmp.find("navigationService").navigate({ 
    type: "standard__webPage", 
    attributes: { 
        url: 'https://www.google.com' 
    } 
});
```

Comment: How are you creating a redirect?

Comment: Updated question with images